# Earth in a timestorm

Tags: story-identification, time

Does anyone know the title of a book where an individual or group ventures through an Earth that is continually swept by timewaves which transport to different era?

Comment: Do the time waves transport Earth as a whole, just the protagonist(s), or many people independently? Were they controlled or random? What eras were depicted (prehistory, future, etc.)? Do you remember when you read that book, was it new then, what was on the cover?

Comment: The waves cross the Earth's surface such that the space between waves is inside a different time in history (past, present or future). The waves would be random but the protagonits might have been able to see what lied on the other side. This would affect many people independently although encounters were told from the point of view of the protagonists who had some purpose for travelling from one point to another. I read the book maybe twenty years or more ago and it was probably written in the seventies or sixties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be *[Time Storm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671721488)* by Gordon R. Dickson.

Comment: That might just be it. The title is obvious but there are many similar themes. The leopard rings a bell :)

Comment: In passing here are some of the covers: http://www.librarything.com/work/138485/covers/

Answer (score 2):

I think that Mike's answer is likely the correct, but there's also "October the first may be too late" by Fred Hoyle which is similar, if less well written.