# Searching for a book involving blocks of fog

Tags: story-identification

I read a book nearly twenty years ago when I was in Jr high.  What I remember is a man traveling around with a teenage girl, (nothing twisted) in a camper I think, and there were these weird blocks of fog or mist. I believe there may have been a dog also. It was a novel in English. I believe it was written in the 70's or 80's. I remember a part in the book where two blocks of the fog got stuck right where a woman's house was. The man and girls stopped there for the night. I remember the girl didn't talk much. That's about all I can remember. I don't even remember the story behind what caused the fog and I really want to reread the book.

Comment: Can you remember any other details? Novel or short story? Did you read it in English? Any character names? Anything about the plot - was the fog alien, trying to kill them, or what?

Comment: It was a novel in English. I believe it was written in the 70's or 80's. I remember a part in the book where two block of the fog got stuck right where a woman's house was. The man and girls stopped there for the night. I remember the girl didn't talk much. That's about all I can remember. I don't even remember the story behind what caused the fog and I really want to reread the book.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4330/earth-in-a-timestorm/

Comment: @Otis you've marked the other question as duplicate but that's fine :p . Better to have this question open in case of further feedback.

Comment: @JamesP. Yes, I pointed this to the earlier one a while back, but this seemed the "better" answer, so I voted to close the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a long stretch, but it's possible you're thinking of Gordon R. Dickson's [*Time Storm*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055312269X)

from one of the reviews on the Amazon link above:

> Gordon Dickson's "Time Storm", first
>   published in 1977, is an excellent post-apocalyptic novel concerning
>   the catastrophic after effects caused by on-going time storms (or time
>   lines that appear as, and are called in the book, 'mistwalls') that
>   continually sweep across sections of the Earth, as well as throughout
>   the universe. As a time storm passes, a large swath of land becomes
>   forever changed in time. A side effect is that for most of the
>   population these time sweeps are deadly.
>       Luckily (or you would have no story), a small
>   percentage of the population (including a few animals) seem immune to
>   the deadly effects of the time storms. The three main characters; the
>   protagonist (Marc Despard), an autistic teenage girl (known as
>   'Girl'), and a leopard (called Sunday), are all richly defined.
>       This story begins with the three unlikely
>   partners traveling across country where they cross area after area
>   that has been changed in time. The people (and/or creatures) that have
>   been 'deposited' into the effected areas (if there are anyone at all),
>   are either from some point in the future or from the past, but like
>   any post-apocalyptic story, few are friendly. Even the survivors of
>   his own time can be, and usually are, extremely dangerous.

Here's the intersection of two mistwalls (possibly your "blocks of fog or mist"):

Chapter 9:

> It did not take long to reach the end of it. I
>   kept on a little further, however, not wanting to turn the corner
>   until I could see behind it. But though we kept going further and
>   further, we still did not seem to quite clear the end. Finally, I saw
>   why. We were not going to be able to see behind that mistwall after
>   all. Here at what I had thought was its point of termination, it had
>   either bent to the right and continued, or run into another mistwall
>   going off at an angle in that direction.
>       At first, all I felt was disappointment that I
>   was not going to get a look behind it. Then it occurred to me that
>   perhaps the reason neither mistwall nor mistwall section had been
>   moving had been because each had butted up against the other; and the
>   two time change lines coming together had somehow created an unusual
>   state or condition that had halted them both. The moment that I
>   thought it, I was hungry to see what was behind the intersection of
>   those two mistwalls.

There is, indeed a house behind the mistwall intersection, inhabited by a lone woman and her pack of trained dogs. The man, girl and leopard were on foot (on bicycles, actually; one of the few post-apocalypse stories where bikes are used) at this point in the story but in the beginning they were driving a panel truck.

Comment: I wondered if it might be this one, but I couldn't remember the protagonists or find my copy.

Comment: Fortunately, there's always [OpenLibrary.org.](https://openlibrary.org/)

Comment: I believes it is Time Storm. I just look it up and recognized the cover art. Awesome, thank you so much. This has honestly been making me crazy since I was 12.

Comment: You're quite welcome, always glad to help.