# What is a story about an entropy storm causing the apocalypse?

Tags: story-identification

My memory is very fuzzy, but a few years ago I read a short story or series of stories (maybe even on reddit?) about an apocalypse scenario.

But the form of the apocalypse was different... as I recall it was sort of an "entropy storm"... slowly rolling across the country from coast to coast. It would disable all advanced electronics first (radios, planes), then mechanical (cars, guns), and eventually the most primitive things, like fire, would stop working.

It was slow moving, too. Such that people had enough time to flee ahead of it... being sort of driven on a massive "migration" by the storm.

I don't remember much other than that. Does anyone else know what I'm talking about?

Google is mostly returning results on The Last Question by Asimov (probably because I keep using entropy as a keyword), but that's definitely not it.

It is also not "Time Storm" as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for a book involving blocks of fog](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108096/searching-for-a-book-involving-blocks-of-fog)

Comment: Just a note because this on the close vote review, but story-id questions should only be marked as duplicates if both have the same accepted answer. As this question (at time of comment) has no answers, I am leaving open.

Comment: Based on the description, I'm fairly confident that it is **not** Time Storm. I don't recall anything about time travel or out-of-time creatures in my story. Also, the "storm" is more like a squeegee, sweeping the whole world from east to west. Not isolated pockets. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: How is this even vaguely being marked as a duplicate? There's no evidence to support that "weird blocks of fog and a girl that doesn't talk much" is the same as an "entropy storm that causes fire to stop working".

Comment: Boy, my instant reaction was Time Storm. Surprised that wasn't it.

Comment: In *Time Storm,* the storm is caused by the universe collapsing in some areas while still expanding in others, i.e. uneven entropy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story was ["East" by Cameron Suey](https://thejosefkstories.com/2012/01/02/east/)

Comment: Great! How did you find it? Also, I'm curious what of your recollection was correct and what wasn't?

Comment: A lot of it was right. But the word entropy doesn't show up anywhere in the text (I just re-read it). Also, I was sort of wrong about the order of operations re: technology failing. Everything stops working at once, roughly, but it does include fire/gunpowder.

A friend at work managed to find it on google with the keywords _"apocalypse storm -"x-men" story energy east coast nomads"_

Comment: Pro-tip: you may want to add that to your answer, to flesh it out a bit. ;)