Sci-fi book in which pockets of time are happening on Earth and things are getting stuck in them
I remember getting a sci-fi book in the last ten years. It had, to my remembrance, a dark cover with orange on the periphery because some of it takes place in an orange grove.
The concept is somehow these pockets of time are happening on Earth and things are getting stuck in them, like one kid is in the barn checking on a tractor or something and gets stuck there and time is either going really slow or fast. It also happens to a little creature of some kind who (maybe?) is found in an old car?
I'm so frustrated I can't remember more because I didn't finish the book but now I really want to.

Could be Gordon R Dickson's  Time storm? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108096/searching-for-a-book-involving-blocks-of-fog

There is no orange grove or tractor in a barn in Time Storm.
